# Как запустить эмулятор Android на процессоре AMD FX8300E

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-sdk

Как запустить эмулятор Android на процессоре AMD FX8300E?
В BIOS виртуализацию включил. В Virtual Box ОС накатываются без проблем.
Genymotion не предлагать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для создания эмулятора используйте образы системы ARM-процессоров (а не Intel)

Comment: Отличный комментарий. Еще бы узнать как это сделать. В настройке виртуальных устройств я не нашел как изменить архитектуру процессора.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В общем то все доступно сказано в сообщении. Для процессоров AMD (и Intel, не поддерживающих технологию VT-x) нельзя использовать образы x86 при создании виртуальных устройств. Вместо этого можно использовать образы на основе архитектуры ARM.

При создании виртуального устройства нажимаете кнопку "+ Create Virtual Device"

На первом экране (Select Hardware) выбираете характеристики виртуального устройства (размер экрана, количество оперативной памяти и тд.). Нажимаете Next/

На втором экране (System Image) выбираете образ OC Android для эмулируемого устройства. Нажимаете на вкладку "Other Images" (третья вкладка) и выбираете там нужную версию ОС у которой в названии в колонке ABI присутствует "armeabi" (или arm64), скорее всего образ придется предварительно скачать (нажать "Download" в первой колонке).

[image: scrn]

Нажимаете Next и заканчиваете работу мастера.

Данный эмулятор будет работать на любом компьютере, но скорость его работы оставляет желать лучшего (процессора Intel с поддержкой VT-x)

PS: В системах на базе Linux (как Ubuntu) поддерживается аппаратная виртуализация не только Intel, но и AMD (технология SVM) и в этих системах эмулятор с хост-машиной на процессорах AMD работает гораздо быстрее.

Comment: Это похоже на ответ. Проверю и отпишу.

Comment: Проверил. Помогло. Но...когда выбирал arm меня IDE информировала что проблемы с виртуализацией есть, несмотря на предупреждения выбрал нужную версию ОС и установил. Теперь эмулятор работает как надо!